# Return a blob object, or binary data in a serveless function

Tags: aws-lambda, backend, blob, serverless

I have a netlify serverless function (which is very similar to AWS lambda) that makes an API call to an API that returns a binary stream for a jpeg image but when I try to return the blob from that binary stream to my frontend code, the blob turns into a default JavaScript object and I can't create its object URL.

This is the code I tried using to return the blob:

```
exports.handler = async(event) => {
    const request = await fetch(
        "https://api-example.com",
        {
            headers: { Authorization: "Bearer MyApiKey" },
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({ inputs: event.queryStringParameters.input }),
        }
    );
    const response = await request.blob();
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({blobObj: response})
    }
}
```

and in my frontend code I have this:

```
async function query(data) {
  const response = await fetch(
        "/.netlify/functions/apiCall?input=" + data,
        {
            method: "GET",
        }
    );
  const result = await response.json();
    return result.blobObj;
}
```

but the object I get is not a blob.